# How to fetch a lot of documents from a MongoDB collection faster?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, flutter, heroku

My collection has 1000-ish records. I have a flutter app, which fetches data from a Heroku API, where the backend is based in NodeJs. While fetching, it sorts the entire collection based on the number of a certain "Vacant" field in descending order. It takes nearly 15 seconds to fetch that data. I really don't think 1000 documents is a lot of data, so what can be the optimal method of approaching this problem?

**UPDATE 1:** This is the code where I'm fetching the data, where I'm sorting based on the 'Vacant' field.

**UPDATE 2:** My region on Heroku was set in the US, that's why there was a huge delay in the response time. Shifted to AWS with a server close to me, the response is in milliseconds now.

```
const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  District: String,
  Name: String,
  Vacant: Number,
  Address: String,
  PhoneNumber: String
})

app.get('/:state', (req, res) => {
  const State = mongoose.model(req.params.state, dataSchema)

  State.find().sort([['Vacant', -1]]).exec((err, foundData) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send(foundData)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: 1000 records shouldn't take that much really, can you post your code? The api access might be the problem too.

Comment: I updated my question with the codeblock where I'm fetching the data.

Comment: Add an index on Vacant and see if it gets faster

Comment: Thanks @BuğraGündüz I added an index on Vacant variable, it has reduced sort times by 50 percent at least. The API fetches the data in less than 5 seconds consistently.